# Tab delimited and shapefile

Tags: shapefile

I have a tab delimited file and a shapefile which demonstrates the forest areas an area. When I open them in a project the shapefile covers the points of my samples. Is there a way to counteract this? This is done regardless of which file I open first.

Comment: What software are you using? Most orders points above polygons by default.

Answer (score 2):

Solution 1:
Depending on your GIS Software, somewhere in your Project you find a list of your loaded layers.
Usually visibility goes top>down .. so just drag your point-layer on top of your shape.

Solution 2:
Change the "Fill" color to transparent and just display the border of the forest polygon(s).

Comment: Boarder is a person who rents a room, border is the edge of an area. This answer is fairly good, given that we have no idea of what software is being used, it fits almost all that I have seen. One would think that the Tab Delimited file is being shown as some sort of event layer, perhaps if that was exported to points (Save As) as shapefile the user may experience a different situation but without knowing what software that's really hard to call.